# Domain not directing to index.html

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, search-engine-indexing, file-manager

I have just completed an FTP upgrade of my whole site. However, it is not working, when you type is [www.gas-sense.co.uk](http://www.gas-sense.co.uk), then you get a splashpage from my shared hosting, as though there is nothing on the site, previously, this would redirect to `/index.html` and would be fine. However, if I go to the file manager and click on http://gas-sense.co.uk/Index.html, I get the site loading as expected. Why is this and how do I get the route domain to direct straight to /index ?

Comment: I'm closing this because you found your solution, the result of a typo.   It is unlikely that this question will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, just spotted it... My `index.html` file had a capital letter - `Index.html` - hence it wasn't recognised!